# Value inside function call not getting reflected outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The price variable inside $.each is printing 5 but the value Outside is printing as 0.Can you
tell me why this is happening and how to correct that.

```
var price=0;
$.getJSON( "http://localhost/temple/price.php?name="+nameofselectedsublist, function( data){

$.each( data, function( key, val ) {

  price=data[key].price;
   console.log(price);
   });
  });


console.log(price+"Outside ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, it doesn't matter if it has finished executing, `console.log(price+"Outside ")` will execute immediately.

Move it inside after `$.getJSON` has finished.

```
var price=0;
$.getJSON( "http://localhost/temple/price.php?name="+nameofselectedsublist, function( data){
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      price=data[key].price;
      console.log(price);
  });
  console.log(price+"Outside ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This a Sync vs Async timing issue, run this and see the timing involved.

```
var price = 0;

$.getJSON( "http://localhost/temple/price.php?name="+nameofselectedsublist, function( data){
    console.log('I RECIEVED THE DATA - async')
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        price = data[key].price;
        console.log(price);

    });

});


console.log(price + "Outside ");
console.log("I'm done running my script... sync");
```

When the `console.log(price + "Outside ");` `price` equals 0; as the $.getJSON call has not gotten it's result back yet...

I found this [article](https://dev.to/hardy613/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-programming-23ed), which may help break things down a bit more.